# Getting a didn't return an HTTPResponse Object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a view in Django that will take user input based on inventory and link it to the different locations in which inventory is taken. When I try to get it up and running, I get the view inventory.views.inventory_entry didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Code below
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Location, Inventory
from .forms import DataForm 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def inventory_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            in_use = form.cleaned_data['in_use']
            training_room = form.cleaned_data['training_room']
            conference_room = form.cleaned_data['conference_room']
            gsm_office = form.cleaned_data['gsm_office']
            prospecting_station = form.cleaned_data['prospecting_station']
            applicant_station = form.cleaned_data['applicant_station']
            visitor_station = form.cleaned_data['visitor_station']
            other = form.cleaned_data['other']
            spare_on_floor = form.cleaned_data['spare_on_floor']
            spare_storage = form.cleaned_data['spare_storage']
            total_spare = form.cleaned_data['total_spare']
            broken = form.cleaned_data['broken']
            total = form.cleaned_data['total']
            
            Inventory.objects.create(location=location, date=date, description=description, 
                                     in_use=in_use, training_room=training_room, conference_room=conference_room,
                                     gsm_office=gsm_office, prospecting_station=prospecting_station, applicant_station=applicant_station,
                                     visitor_station=visitor_station, other=other, spare_on_floor=spare_on_floor, spare_storage=spare_storage,
                                     total_spare=total_spare, broken=broken, total=total)
            return redirect('data_entry')
        
        else:
            form = DataForm()
            
        locations = Location.objects.all()
        return render(request, "inventory/index.html", {'form':form, 'locations': locations})
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

OFFICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Akron, OH', 'AKRON'),
    ('Atlanta, GA', 'ATLANTA'),
    ('Austin, TX', 'AUSTIN'),
    ('Birmingham, AL', 'BIRGMINGHAM'),
    ('Boston, MA', 'BOSTON'),
    ('Charleston, SC', 'CHARLESTON_SC'),
    ('Charleston, WV', 'CHARLESTON_WV'),
    ('Charlotte, NC', 'CHARLOTTE'),
    ('Chicago West, IL', 'CHICAGO_WEST'),
    ('Chicago, IL', 'CHICAGO'),
    ('Cleveland, OH', 'CLEVELAND'),
    ('Denver, CO', 'DENVER'),
    ('Dallas, TX', 'DALLAS'),
    ('Evansville, IN', 'EVANSVILLE'),
    ('Fayetteville, AR', 'FAYETTEVILLE'),
    ('Ft Lauderdale, FL', 'FT LAUDERDALE'),
    ('Ft Wayne, IN', 'FT WAYNE'),
    ('Grand Rapids, MI', 'GRAND RAPIDS'),
    ('Greensboro, NC', 'GREENSBORO'),
    ('Greenville, SC', 'GREENVILLE'),
    ('Houston, TX', 'HOUSTON'),
    ('Indianapolis, IN', 'INDIANAPOLIS'),
    ('Jacksonville, FL', 'JACKSONVILLE'),
    ('Kansas City, MO', 'KANSAS CITY'),
    ('Knoxville, TN', 'KNOXVILLE'),
    ('Las Vegas, NV', 'LAS VEGAS'),
    ('Lexington, KY', 'LEXINGTON'),
    ('Louisville, KY', 'LOUISVILLE'),
    ('Memphis, TN', 'MEMPHIS'),
    ('Milwaukee, WI', 'MILWAUKEE'),
    ('Minneapolis, MN', 'MINNEAPOLIS'),
    ('Mobile, AL', 'MOBILE'),
    ('Nashville, TN', 'NASHVILLE'),
    ('New Orleans, LA', 'NEW ORLEANS'),
    ('Orlando, FL', 'ORLANDO'),
    ('Phoenix, AZ', 'PHOENIX'),
    ('Pittsburgh, PA', 'PITTSBURGH'),
    ('Portland, OR', 'PORTLAND'),
    ('Raleigh, NC', 'RALEIGH'),
    ('Richmond, VA', 'RICHMOND'),
    ('Salt Lake City, UT', 'SALT LAKE CITY'),
    ('San Antonio, TX', 'SAN ANTONIO'),
    ('Savannah, GA', 'SAVANNAH'),
    ('St Louis, MO', 'ST LOUIS'),
    ('Tampa, FL', 'TAMPA'),
    ('Toledo, OH', 'TOLEDO'),    
)

class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=OFFICE_CHOICES, default='Select the office')
def __str__(self):
    return self.location_name

class Inventory(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # location = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=OFFICE_CHOICES, default='Select the office')
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    in_use = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    training_room = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    conference_room = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gsm_office = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    prospecting_station = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    applicant_station = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    visitor_station = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    other = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    spare_on_floor = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    spare_storage = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_spare = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    broken = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
def __str__(self):
    return f"Data for location {self.location} on {self.date}"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Location

class DataForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all())
    date = forms.DateField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    in_use = forms.IntegerField()
    training_room = forms.IntegerField()
    conference_room = forms.IntegerField()
    gsm_office = forms.IntegerField()
    prospecting_station = forms.IntegerField()
    applicant_station = forms.IntegerField()
    visitor_station = forms.IntegerField()
    other = forms.IntegerField()
    spare_on_floor = forms.IntegerField()
    spare_storage = forms.IntegerField()
    total_spare = forms.IntegerField()
    broken = forms.IntegerField()
    total = forms.IntegerField()
```

I have tried the above code. I am hoping I can get this to render in an HTML page to take users' input and attach it to the different locations.

Comment: Share `data_entry` to see where you have made mistake.

Comment: So that was supposed to be inventory_entry which I have fixed and am still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling requests which are not POST (probably indentation problem). You can change your code like this:

```
def inventory_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
           return redirect('data_entry')
        # no need to handle form invalid , otherwise it will not render form errors. Also, the final return will return this form either way.

    else:
        form = DataForm()
    locations = Location.objects.all()
    return render(request, "inventory/index.html", {'form':form, 'locations': locations})
```

Comment: thank you I updated my code but am still getting the same result

Comment: Are you sure the indentations are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data_entry` view does not return Http Object. You need to make sure, that every possible situation has some `HttpResponse` or `redirect` in that view.